# Git config located in H: drive

Tags: git, config

I have `Windows 7 32 bit` and was recently looking for my `.gitconfig` file and trying to reverse engineer my companies proxy script so that I could use it to my advantage and clone repositories and such. However during my excavations I found that I have multiple `.gitconfig` files in multiple locations and it seems that when I write to my config file for my proxy and then run a `git config --list --show-origin` I get the following output while not being inside any repos and being on my desktop:

```
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.symlinks=false
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.autocrlf=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.fscache=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.diff=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.status=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.branch=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.interactive=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       help.format=html
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       http.sslcainfo=C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/my-cert.crt
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       rebase.autosquash=true
file:"C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"        credential.helper=manager
file:H://.gitconfig     user.name=me
file:H://.gitconfig     user.email=my email
file:H://.gitconfig     url.https://.insteadof=git://
file:H://.gitconfig     url.https://github.com.insteadof=git://github.com
```

Lets say I wanted to write the proxy script to my git config:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://domain.com:80
git config --global http.proxy %HTTP_PROXY%
```

Then show the config file again:

```
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.symlinks=false
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.autocrlf=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       core.fscache=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.diff=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.status=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.branch=auto
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       color.interactive=true
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       help.format=html
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       http.sslcainfo=C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/my-cert.crt
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config"       rebase.autosquash=true
file:"C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\mingw64/etc/gitconfig"        credential.helper=manager
file:H://.gitconfig     user.name=me
file:H://.gitconfig     user.email=my email
file:H://.gitconfig     url.https://.insteadof=git://
file:H://.gitconfig     url.https://github.com.insteadof=git://github.com
file:H://.gitconfig     http.proxy=%HTTP_PROXY%
```

It writes it to the H: drive, is this normal behavior for git? If not how can I fix this to where it will write it to the correct location?

---

Just to make things clear, I do have a git repo's in my H: drive, these aren't linked to github and are just repos that anyone can pull from, through the shared drive

Comment: Us H: your user home folder by any chance?

Comment: @Gimby No it is not.